# In Python, for loop one file to search another

Tags: python, paramiko, readlines

Would appreciate some leads on how to enhance my python script to address a problem.  I have a file which lists thousands of mobile workstations and IP addresses which gets updated every five minutes.  I use Paramiko to ssh into each workstation to verify if a service is running (in this example crond).  The problem I run into is when I start my python script it reads the large file into memory and by the time it gets 1/3 of the way down the IP addresses have changed and the majority of the IP address are no longer valid.  Is there a way to have python open then close the file before workstation each search?  This would ensure the IP is the current IP. The python script I wrote below works but again, I have the problem with old IP information.  Thank you.

```
The contents of WKSIPS.txt are in the format:

WORK  1234  Cell IP: 10.10.10.10
WORK  4567  Cell IP: 10.10.10.11

#!/usr/bin/python
import paramiko, os, string, threading
import getpass
import socket
import sys

FileName=open('WKSIPS.txt', 'r')
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

for line in FileName.readlines():
    WKSid = line.split()
    try:
        if WKSid[0] == 'WORK' :
            WKSip = WKSid[4]   
            ssh.connect(WKSip, username='user', password='password', timeout='3')
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('service crond status')
            Out =  stdout.readlines()
            print ("WORK  " + WKSid[1], Out)
            ssh.close()
            FileName.close
   except paramiko.SSHException, e:
       print ('WORK' + WKSid, WKSip, "Invalid Password")
```

Comment: If you closed and re-opened the file as you suggest, would you want to start over at the beginning of the "new" file?  Or at the same line you left off?  Would starting at the same line cause any problems (e.g. the number of lines change)?

Comment: You could use the [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) to do some of the work in parallel. At the very least, you could have subprocesses do the ssh work so you're not blocking the file reading.

Comment: Because this workstation names are static and only the IP address change I'd need it to pick up where it left off.

Comment: Does the order of the lines change?  Does the number of lines change?

Comment: What happens if you run your command on an invalid IP address? Is that an event you can identify and choose to ignore?

Comment: I have an exception to print "Timed Out"

Comment: The order and lines stay the same..only change in IP address.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a [multiprocessing pool](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) to create workers that can handle the each line of the file for you, which would allow you to get through the file faster.

My goal with this code snippet **is to sidestep the file reloading issue entirely** by making your script fast enough to complete before the 5 minute file refresh.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import paramiko, os, string, threading
import multiprocessing
import getpass
import socket
import sys

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

def worker(line)
    WKSid = line.split()
    try:
        if WKSid[0] == 'WORK' :
            WKSip = WKSid[4]

            ssh.connect(WKSip, username='user', password='password', timeout='3')
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('service crond status')
            Out =  stdout.readlines()
            print ("WORK  " + WKSid[1], Out)
            ssh.close()
    except paramiko.SSHException, e:
        print ('WORK' + WKSid, WKSip, "Invalid Password")

# set up processing pool
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

with open('WKSIPS.txt') as infile:
    pool.map(worker, infile)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Notes:

- I've moved the main part of your script's functionality into a function that accepts a line of the file as input. `pool.map()` will feed each worker one line of the file iterator and they will handle it independently. It's doing the same thing as your original code, but the work is split among a number of processes that is equal to the number of cores on your machine.
- I don't have the paramiko module and can't install it on in my current environment, so I can't really test this code for you. My apologies in advance if there are any errors.
- I'm not familiar with the paramiko library, so there may be some hidden side-effects of using the same `paramikio.SSHClient()` object in in multiple processes simultaneously. If you see odd errors from the `ssh` object, try moving its instantiation into the worker function.
- I've changed `readlines()` into using a Python file iterator. Reading a whole file into memory is a time-consuming operation, and should be avoided.

Just to be perfectly clear, this code snippet **does not** handle changes to the file that occur while it is running. I've made two big assumptions:

1. The execution of this script can be synced with whatever operation refreshes the file so that it executes immediately after the file is refreshed.
2. It can execute under 5 minutes - since I don't have paramiko, access to the ssh targets, or access to WKSIPS.txt, so I can't time it. Since this problem seems to fit the definition of [embarassingly parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel), I think it's worth a try. It will be up to the OP to optimize further if it doesn't meet the time spec.

Comment: The multiprocessing pool approach seems like a good idea, but changes to the file mid-run won't be reflected as the code is currently written.

Comment: That's true. I've made the assumption that the running of this script can be sync with the file refresh. I'll edit to clarify that.

Comment: I appreciate the multiprocessing suggestion but due to some of these workstations being connected over radio, it's doubtful it will complete in five minutes.  Currently, the way I have it written, it takes over 4 hours due to latency in the establishment of the ssh connections.

Comment: @gineraso Oh. Well damn. There goes that idea.

Comment: @gineraso For what it's worth, I'd still recommend you implement some kind of parallelism after you straighten out handling file refreshes. With multiple processes handling the SSH connections, you could still see a very significant reduction in run time.

Comment: You're right, fixing this issue will not speed up the run time.  I'll make sure and incorporate multiprocessing into the final solution.  Thank you.

Comment: This is an interesting problem that I'm going to revisit when I have time. I'll see what I can come up with and adjust my answer later on if I have any more complete ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This is *very* expensive, but I think its nonetheless the first step to seeing whether this approach will work for you:

```
import re
import paramiko

def verify_service(ssh, work, ip):
    print("Verifying workstation %d at %s" % (work, ip))
    ssh.connect(ip, username='user', password='password', timeout='3')
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('service crond status')
    print ("WORK  " + work, stdout.readlines())
    ssh.close()

IP_LIST = 'WKSIPS.txt'
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# Get number of lines in WKSIPS -- if you know this, you can just define NUM_LINES
NUM_LINES = None
with open(IP_LIST) as f:
    NUM_LINES = len(f.readlines())

for i in xrange(NUM_LINES):
    with open(IP_LIST) as f:
        #line = f.readlines()[i]
        line = next(islice(f, i, None))
        mat = re.match(r'WORK\s*(\d+)\s*Cell IP: (.*)', line)
        if mat:
            verify_service(ssh, int(mat.group(1)), mat.group(2))
```

The code first opens your file and counts the number of lines, storing it in `NUM_LINES`.  If you know this number, you can get rid of the `NUM_LINES = None` line and the two below it and just replace it with `NUM_LINES = <number of lines>`.

Then, for each line number `i` between 0 and `NUM_LINES` (exclusive), it opens the file, <s>*reads the entire file into a list*, pulls out the line corresponding to line number `i`</s> iterates over the lines until it gets to the `i`th line, parses it and passes it to the `verify_service()` function -- which you'll have to update with your paramiko code.

If this works, you should think about better ways to do this.  Maybe you don't have to re-read the file every iteration, maybe every *n* iterations works just as well.  Maybe you hash the file and check whether the hash changed before you re-read it.  Maybe you check the modification time of the file, etc.  Maybe you use subprocesses and try to handle multiple connections simultaneously instead of consecutively.

In any case, if this works, you should look to optimize it -- as it is very expensive as currently written, but it will do what you stated you wanted.

Comment: I think you're right, there has to be a better way to do this.  Let me give you solution a try to see if does what I need.  Thank you.